# ContentEditable Div onInput prevented by website shortcuts

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension that can be open on different websites. I have a contentEditable div that I can write into but if a website that I am on has some keyboard shortcuts(for example pressing W scrolls up) then this key is not triggering the onInput event of my div. Is there anyway to disable the site shortcuts while the div is onFocus?

I am not sure how to go around this problem